Android Hilt type (ERROR annotation type): error.NonExistentClass error
I am studying Hilt now.
We added @AndroidEntryPoint for Activity
ViewModel has set up @HiltViewModel
Module Class has been created.
But now I am experiencing the following error.
What is my problem?
Dependency trace:
=> element (CLASS): kr.co.example.viewmodel.TestViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule
=> element (METHOD): binds(kr.co.example.viewmodel.TestViewModel)
=> annotation type: LazyClassKey
=> type (ERROR annotation type): error.NonExistentClass

This is My Activity Code

This is My ViewModel

My Module is

What is Wrong..
